# Visual Studio Code does not open file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, visual-studio-code

So I created a .txt file, called nice.txt.I placed it into a folder along  with my python file.Whenever I save the python file,a **pycache** folder is made up, with a file having the extension of pyc.
I followed a tutorial on how to read files, write to them and stuff, but I just open the python file, and it doesn't return anything.

I tried putting "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true, to the settings.

```
with open('nice.txt') as infp:
    data = infp.read()

print(data)
input()
```

It should just open the file,read it and when I run the python file the text inside should be printed out.

Comment: What is your output now?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you are running your file. In the body of your question you are only talking about saving it, but how are you executing it?

Comment: add `print("Here: ", infp)` inside the `with`